# Variance of the number of digits in PINs

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a task:

A 5-digit pin is valid when all digits are different. So a set of correct pins:
$A=\{(d_1,d_2, d_3, d_4, d_5):d_{i}\in \{0,...,9\},i\in \{1,...,5\}, \forall_{(i\ne j, i,j \in \{1,2,3,4,5 \})}  d_{i} \ne d_{j} \} $

Two PINs were randomly and independently drawn from the $A$ set. Let $X$ be the number of different digits that appear in both PINs.
Calculate $Var(X)$.

I tried from definition:$Var(X)=EX^2-(EX)^2$, so I tried to calculate:
$P(X=5)=\frac{{10 \choose 5}5!(5!-1) }{{10 \choose 5}^2(5!-1)5!}$.
But later I have no idea how to calculate $P(X=6)$ in the easy way.
Please help me to solve this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get the mean by linearity.  Then you can compute $E[X^2]$ the same way, taking care to handle the cross terms properly.

Comment: please fix your question, you included $i=0$ in the definition of $A$

Comment: To your specific question:  $P(X=6)$ is $0$.  It is not possible to have $6$ distinct digits which appear in even one string of length $<6$.  And your computation of $P(X=5)$ seems off.  Fixing the first string, the probability that the second contains the same digits (possibly in a different order) is $1\big /\binom {10}5$.

Comment: "You can get the mean by linearity. Then you can compute E[X2] the same way, taking care to handle the cross terms properly"- i do not know how to get the mean by linearity. Could you show me? X=6 for example for two PINs: (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,3,4,6). We have 6 digits. So P(X=6) is not 0.

Comment: About P(X=5) you are right. I corrected post.

Answer (score 1):

> i do not know how to get the mean by linearity.

It refers to applying the Linearity of Expectation to the sum of Indicator Random Variables.

Let $X_i = 1$ when digit at position $i$ is different in the PINs, and $X_i = 0$ when the digit is identical at that position.   These are indicator random variables.   $X_i, X_j$ will be independent for all $i\neq j$.

$$\forall i{\in}\{1,2,3,4,5\}~.\mathsf P(X_i=1)=\dfrac{1}{10}$$

Then $\mathsf E(X_i)=1\cdot\mathsf P(X_i{=}1)$ and $X=\sum_{i=1}^5 X_i$ . So we may use Linearity of Expectation to find: $$\textstyle{~~\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E\left(\sum_{i=1}^5 X_i\right)\\\mathsf E(X^2)=\mathsf E\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^5 X_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^5 X_j\right)\right)}$$

---

Update: If you are counting $X$ as *"distinct digits that appear in the two PINs"* then the solution shall just use slightly different indicators.

Let $Y_k$ indicate that digit $k$ appears in at least one among the PINs. So for all $k\in[[0..9]]$ and $\ell\in[[0..9]]$ when $k\neq\ell$:

Thus, as above : $$\textstyle{~~\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E\left(\sum_{k=0}^9 Y_k\right)\\\mathsf E(X^2)=\mathsf E\left(\left(\sum_{k=0}^9 Y_k\right)\left(\sum_{\ell=0}^9 Y_\ell\right)\right)}$$

You just need to evaluate$\mathsf P(Y_k=1)$ and $\mathsf P(Y_k=1,Y_\ell=1)$

Comment: OK, thanks, but I do not see solution. I do not know if we write about the same task. If we have for example two PINs: $(1,2,3,4,5)  (1,2,3,4,6)$ the $X=6$. If we have for example two PINs: $(1,2,3,4,5)  (6,7,8,9,10)$ the $X=10$.

Comment: How are you counting $X$, the "number of different digits"?  I get $1$ in the first case because there is a one digit difference between the PINs, and $5$ in the second.

Comment: Ah, wait.  You are counting *distinct digits in* the two PINs.  That will require a different solution.  Let me think on it a bit.

Comment: No... its a similar solution, just with a different indicator.  Let $Y_k$ be the indicator that digit $k$ occurs in at least one PIN.  Then $$\textstyle\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E(\sum_{k=0}^{9}Y_k)\text{ and }\mathsf E(X^2)=\mathsf E((\sum_{k=0}^9 Y_k)(\sum_{\ell=0}^9 Y_\ell))$$ Note that $Y_k,Y_\ell$ will not be independent when $k\neq\ell$, so you shall have to evaluate $\mathsf E(Y_kY_\ell)=\mathsf P(Y_k=1,Y_\ell=1)$ (the probability that two digits each occur in the PINs).